# NGINX proxy_pass via corporate http_proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to set up NGINX to proxy requests from a specific location to the internet, but I need to go through a corporate proxy. Configuration exmaple:

```
location /test {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://<service_accessible_through_the_internet>/test;
}
```

the problem is that NGINX tries to access the service in the internet without using the proxy (opposite from exporting http_proxy and using curl), and therefore returns timeouts.
Is there a possibility to configure the NGINX to work as described?
Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/583743/how-to-make-an-existing-caching-nginx-proxy-use-another-proxy-to-bypass-a-firewa).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I have already read this solution and it didn't worked for me before, but now I understand why. I was trying to configure reverse proxy to HTTPS which is not possible as written in this page.